# Can ios simulator can be run in Windows

Tags: ios, automation, appium, emulation

I m working on appium scripting for mobile application automation testing.
I m able to simulate android device using the emulator and run the script in the emulator.

Now my next task is to run in ios. Please let me know it is possible to do it in ios emulator in Windows machine. If so some headsup on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can not. There are platforms like React Native, Flutter, Xamarin, etc which enables you develop iOS applications; but when it comes to debugging and deployment, you have to have a macOS, which in turn requires a Macintosh machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yess you can use Remote simulator to windows by enabling it under

Tools >> Option >> Xamarin >> IOS setting >> Remote simulator to windows.

But you still need active mac agent connection to build your app

Comment: would you mind exxagerating more on that? I m actually clue less

Comment: And am looking for something java based, Xamarin seems to work in c# only I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appium studio **free** community edition for testing iOS physical device from windows machine.

note:- I have tested appium studio personally and think it will be useful for others.