# How to test my app on an iphone from my PC

Tags: ios, flutter, testing

So I've been building a flutter app in Android Studio. I'd like to be able to test it on a device but apple tends to be a pain when it comes to testing on Iphone. I have an iphone 7 I'm not currently using that I'd be willing to jailbreak. Does anyone know how I can test on my device? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter)

Comment: Until you don't use cloud devices that can be accessed from a PC, there is no option. This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565046/can-ios-simulator-can-be-run-in-windows which contains some answers.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can test your app without owning a Mac is by using https://codemagic.io/, which i do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run your app in debug mode on your iphone without having a mac.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious suggestion would be to run a virtual Mac machine, but I think this is not legally possible. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac device almost surely to be able to test the app from your PC. There are a few options that let you develop for iOS from a PC, and test your app. However, eventually you'll require anyway a Mac device for App store submission.